# Is there any way to enforce certain size(of) class C by adding appropriate space/padding after its attributes?

Tags: c++

Usual way to enforce size of a class is to add a padding of appropriate size:

```
class C 
{    
    int foo;
    uint8_t padding[PADDINGSIZE];
};
```

The `sizeof(C)` may be then also verified using `static_assert`.

But this is inconvenient. Is there any reliable solution to enforce `sizeof(C)` to a specific value with or without padding but without a necessity of specifying `PADDINGSIZE`?

Comment: You will need more to convince the compiler though. e.g. #pragma pack(1)

Comment: Whatever the solution you choose, I'd recommend adding a the `static_assert` so the compiler will warn you if the intended solution does not work as expected.

Comment: Can you explain what the use case is?

Comment: @Klaus It is a POD stored/dumped somewhere and have to have an exact size in current and future versions (according to strict specification).

Answer (score 2):

Your best option would probably be to use a `union`. Roughly speaking, with some details missing:

```
class C 
{    
    int foo;
};

union CAlloc
{
    C instance;
    std::byte enforced_size[DESIRED_SIZE];
};
```

Then use `CAlloc::instance` where needed.

Update: as @Mgetz pointed out in the comments, `std::byte` is a C++17 addition, you may want/need to use `char` if you're using an older standard.

Comment: This enforces a _minimum_ size and not a certain size as OP requested.  Yet even though OP did not ask for a _minimum_, it still may meet OP's true unstated goal.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 has introduced new keyword: [alignas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) I think this is something more handy from your point of view.

Answer (score 0):

In *general*, I'd say not possible to enforce certain size(of) class.

Consider a desired size of 13.  `int foo; uint8_t padding[13 - sizeof(int)];` is not going to make a class a size of 13 as certainly padding will occur after `.padding[]`.

The desired `PADDINGSIZE` will need to meet conditions depending on  prior members in the class and minimum class alignment requirements.  Of course there is a minimum as `uint8_t padding[some_negative];` will not work.

Consider below where `PADDINGSIZE + 7` may need to be a multiple of 8 to avoid *padding* after `.padding[]`.

```
class C2 {    
    int foo;
    double d;
    int uint8_t b[1];
    uint8_t padding[PADDINGSIZE];
}
```